# Adding child element to list in xml using xslt is not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="exceptions"/>
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And I want to append an element to the `<targets>` list. I'm trying with the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/t:nlog/targets">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <target xsi:type="File" name="general"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I just get the identity transformation and the new element is not getting added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element `targets` belongs to `t` namespace, so the query should be `/t:nlog/t:targets`

Comment: When I try that I get ` Unknown xsi:type in element being validated: Null`.

Comment: I can get around that by using something like `<xsl:template match="/t:nlog/t:targets[@xsi:type='xs:any']">` but the result still doesn't append my element. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @kovac, I tested it here: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-validator-tester-online.php